# Enter Unicode character into a ActiveX Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex

I am trying to append the Ohm symbol (Ω) in the TextBox.Value when creating the textbox on an Excel worksheet.

The Ohm character unicode (hex) value is 2126.

The code puts a ? in the place of the special character.

```vb
    Set objTxtBx = ws.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.TextBox.1")
    With objTxtBx
        .Name = "LG_tb_17_S" & x & "_NG"
        .Left = lft
        .Width = w
        .Top = t2
        .Object.BackStyle = 0
        .Object.TextAlign = 2
        .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
        .Object.MultiLine = False
        ' .Object.Caption = "String " & x & " Measured"
        .Object.AutoSize = False
        .Object.BorderStyle = 1
        .Object.Value = DataEntryForm.Controls(objTxtBx.Name).Value & ChrW(2126)
        With .Object.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 10
            .Underline = False
        End With
        .Object.WordWrap = False
        .Height = h
                
        h = .Height
        t = .Top
        nT = .Top
        t5 = .Top
    End With
    lft = lft + w
End If
```

Revised Code:

```
Sub creatBox()
Set ws = Sheet1
x = 1

Set objTxtBx = ws.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.TextBox.1")
With objTxtBx
    .Name = "Test1"
    .Left = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 30
    .Object.BackStyle = 0
    .Object.TextAlign = 2
    .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
    .Object.MultiLine = False
    ' .Object.Caption = "String " & x & " Measured"
    .Object.AutoSize = False
    .Object.BorderStyle = 1
    .Object.Value = 1 & " " & ChrW(937)
    With .Object.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Bold = False
        .Size = 14
        .Underline = False
    End With
    .Object.WordWrap = False

End With
End Sub
```

Solution:
Had to move the `.Object.Value = 1 & " " & ChrW(937)` below the `.Font` setting to get the Ohm sign to work all the time.  Not sure why if it was above `.Font` it didn't show correctly when the textbox didn't have focus.

Solution Code:

```
Sub creatBox()
Set ws = Sheet1

Set objTxtBx = ws.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.TextBox.1")
With objTxtBx
    .Name = "Test1"
    .Left = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 30
    .Object.BackStyle = 0
    .Object.TextAlign = 2
    .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
    .Object.MultiLine = False
    '  .Object.Caption = "String " & x & " Measured"
    .Object.AutoSize = False
    .Object.BorderStyle = 1

    With .Object.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Bold = False
        .Size = 14
        .Underline = False
    End With
    .Object.WordWrap = False
    .Object.Value = 1 & " " & ChrW(937)

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 937 seems to work.

Comment: ChrW(937) does work but only when the textbox has focus.  When the textbox doesn't have focus or when it is printed it looks like O.

Comment: Using hex values you need to prefix numbers with **"&H..."**: `ChrW(&H3A9)` ... or write the decimal value `ChrW(937)` instead as @SJR proposed.

Comment: The issue is that it only looks like an Ohm symbol when the Textbox has focus and a O when the textbox loses focus.  Both ChrW(&H3A9) & ChrW(937) behave the same way.  Is it possible I need a reference added to get it to function properly?

Comment: If you can post an [mcve] we might be able to investigate.

Comment: @SJR, I added modified code with issue.  Additionally, I am using Excel 365.

Comment: Sorry don't know what causes that but can you try with a forms textbox (or shape) - activex controls are known to be buggy?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry initially posted Solution in wrong location:
Had to move the .Object.Value = 1 & " " & ChrW(937) below the .Font setting to get the Ohm sign to work all the time.  Not sure why if it was above .Font it didn't show correctly when the textbox didn't have focus.

Below is the Solution Code:

```
Sub creatBox()
Set ws = Sheet1

Set objTxtBx = ws.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.TextBox.1")
With objTxtBx
    .Name = "Test1"
    .Left = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Top = 20
    .Height = 30
    .Object.BackStyle = 0
    .Object.TextAlign = 2
    .Object.SpecialEffect = 0
    .Object.MultiLine = False
'            .Object.Caption = "String " & x & " Measured"
    .Object.AutoSize = False
    .Object.BorderStyle = 1

    With .Object.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Bold = False
        .Size = 14
        .Underline = False
    End With
    .Object.WordWrap = False
    .Object.Value = 1 & " " & ChrW(937)

End With
```

End Sub